# What are your recommended Windows Server 2003 Backup Tools?

Tags: sql-server, windows, backup

What tools do you guys recommend for backing up files and SQL Server databases on Windows 2003?

I'm looking for tools to run daily backups of both files and SQL Server databases. Compress them up and stick them on NAS drives.

I'm looking for cheap / FREE options if possible.

Comment: Not really a programming question.  More of an IT question.

Comment: maybe you should ask something about an progammable API as well...that way its a programming question!

Comment: Or formulate the question for [the software recommendations site](http://www.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) in case you are interested in software

Answer (score 2):

Here at my company I do the following.

At the end of the day I take a full back-up, using a SQL Server job. The syntax for this is well documented in BOL however here is an example:

```
    BACKUP DATABASE [DATABASE]
    TO DISK = '[PATH]\[DATABASE].BAK'
    WITH INIT;
```

I then execute a .bat file that runs a compression process using a free Zip utility to make the files smaller before been shipped off.

During the day I have 4 transaction log backup jobs that run every 10-12 minutes. Each backing up to a separate file.

Then Every hour I run a differential back-up (this will back-up only the differences since the last back-up) I then destroy the transaction files and start again.

Hope that gives you a little info on how it can be done in SQL Server without any 3rd party costly tools.

Comment: Which free zip utility do you use? I've played around with PowerArchiver for doing this as they have a scheduled zip function built in. This was very unreliable though so I stopped using it.

Comment: Hi, we use something called 7-zip. The previous guy before me had it installed and I've never had reason to upgrade or remove it. No reliability problems at all. Runs with a simple source - destination command call.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like the one tool could handle both my SQL compression plus my file backups as well.

Answer (score 1):

Free sql backup software might not exist. Have you ever try Windows Built-in tool? I am not so clear about what they can do really because I just totally lose my confidence on MS.

Before it is NTBackup and then replaced it by Windows Server Backup. A lot of people complaining that it is buggy and always run into errors with implicit reasons.

So you'd better try third-party one. Now windows server/[ms sql and exchange backup](http://backup-sql-server.com/) are developed rapidly and most of them are affordable with around backup solutions. Try to do backup, it would help you a lot.